Почему дает ошибку, что не так?
Ошибка: browser-polyfill.js:817 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected at most 1 argument for set(), got 2
Мой сервис для работы с storage chrome:
import { storage, runtime } from "webextension-polyfill";

export const chromeStorage = {
    handleChromeStorage: (storedArea = 'local', method, ...args) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                storage[storedArea][method](...args, (res) => {
                    if (runtime.lastError) {
                        return reject[runtime.lastError];
                    }
                    resolve(res);
                })
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    },
    setItem: (key, value, storedArea = 'local') => {
        return chromeStorage.handleChromeStorage(storedArea, 'set', { [key]: value })
    },
    getItem: (key, storedArea = 'local') => {
        return chromeStorage.handleChromeStorage(storedArea, 'get', [key]).then(res => res?.[key]);
    },
    removeItem: (key, storedArea = 'local') => {
        return chromeStorage.handleChromeStorage(storedArea, 'remove', [key]);
    },
    clear: (storedArea = 'local') => {
        return chromeStorage.handleChromeStorage(storedArea, 'clear');
    }
}

Пример работы:
import { chromeStorage } from '../../services/storage';

chromeStorage.setItem('settings', {test: 123})

console.log(chromeStorage.getItem('settings'))


А при чём тут reactjs?
